# Text fading in a clip in Shotcut

Tags: video, editing, shotcut

I make YouTube videos sometimes and Shotcut has always been my go-to for video editing, but I am working on a video now and can't figure out how to fade text in and out while a clip is playing. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a long time since you asked the question. Maybe you have found your answer to your question in mean time. I am going to answer it anyway for you and for all others that are using this video editor.

I am using Shotcut in version 17.03.02.

There are probably more elegant and simple ways of doing this. The way I like to do it create a SVG file with the text I want (for example in Inkscape). I import this SVG into Shotcut and put in a separate video track above the main track and leave compositing enabled. Then I add fade-in and fade-out video filters to the SVG-Text video and enable the option "Adjust opacity instead of fade with black" for both filters. You can also adjust the duration of the filter/filters.

So to sum up:

1. create **svg** file with your text
2. add a **video track** with the svg file
3. leave **compositing on**
4. add **fade-in/out filters** and adjust duration
5. **check** "Adjust opacity instead of fade with black" in both fade filters

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. One improvement I would suggest is instead of creating a dedicated SVG for each text overlay I found it quicker to create a single fully transparent PNG the same dimensions as the video. Add the PNG to the new video track wherever you want to show text. Add a Text filter with the message you want to display (in addition to Fade-In / Fade-Out). This workflow makes it easier to adjust the text message and styles directly in Shotcut. Also you can reuse the same PNG for all text in the video rather than having to create a dedicated SVG each time.